# Variadic Templates with Concepts

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, variadic-templates, c++-concepts

I've tested variadic templates inside a function, which I developed step by step.

```cpp
template <typename... Ts>
void foo (Ts...) noexcept {}

// Test code
int i {123};
int j {456};
foo(1,2,3,i,j);
```

It compiles.

Then I added a forwarding reference.

```
template <typename... Ts>
void foo (Ts&&...) noexcept {}

// Test code
int i {123};
int j {456};
foo(1,2,3,i,j);
```

This still compiles.
At last, I decided to add a concept to contrain the function to work only with numbers.

```
template <typename T>
concept MyNumber =
  (is_integral_v<T> || is_floating_point_v<T>);

template <MyNumber... Ts>
void foo (Ts&&...) noexcept {}

// Test code
int i {123};
int j {456};
foo(1,2,3,i,j); // does not compile
foo(1,2,3); // compiles
```

It does NOT compile. The solution would be to remove `&&` in `foo`'s signature, or `i` and `j` to pass with `std::forward`.
What is here the best practice? The usage of `foo` should be easy as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with forwarding references `T&&` is that

- if you pass an lvalue of type `int` (e.g. `i`) to the function,

  - `T` deduces to `int&`, and
  - `T&&` collapses to `int&` (see [reference collapsing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Reference_collapsing))
- if you pass an rvalue of type `int` (e.g. `0`) to the function,

  - `T` deduces to `int`, and
  - `T&&` is simply `int&&`

In other words, the `Ts` in your variadic function template are sometimes references `int&`, and sometimes the type `int` itself. `is_integral_v<T>` is not `true` when `T` is a reference because e.g. `int&` is not an integral type, it is a reference.

#### Solution A - Use values instead of forwarding references

```cpp
template <MyNumber... Ts>
void foo(Ts...) noexcept {}
// or with abbreviated function templates:
void foo(MyNumber auto...) noexcept {}
```

This is perfectly fine and actually better than using forwarding references because `MyNumber` is only satisfied by small fundamental types like `int` and `float` that you should better pass by value  anyway.

Personally, I think this solution is more elegant then the alternative:

#### Solution B - Remove references when checking constraints

```cpp
template <typename... Ts>
  requires ((MyNumber<std::remove_cvref_t<Ts>> && ...))
void foo(Ts&&...) noexcept {}
```

This would remove the `&` from `int&` when you're passing `foo(i)` for the purpose of checking whether it satisfies `MyNumber`.

#### Note on the `MyNumber` concept

Ideally, concepts should be built from other concepts so that some concepts can be made more constrained than others:

```cpp
#include <concepts>

template <typename T>
concept MyNumber = std::integral<T> || std::floating_point<T>;
```

Only use type traits like `std::is_integral_v` when there is no equivalent concept in the standard library.

Answer (score 3):

For built-in types passing by value is fine, so removing `&&` is correct.

For more general cases, you actually want to check template without reference/cv-qualifier, so use [`std::remove_cvref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cvref)/[`std::decay`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) in your concept or constraint:

```
template <typename T>
concept MyNumber =
  (is_integral_v<std::remove_cvref_t<T>> || is_floating_point_v<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>);
```

or

```
template <typename... Ts>
requires ((MyNumber<std::remove_cvref_t<Ts>> && ...))
void foo (Ts&&...) noexcept;
```

Answer (score 1):

When testing types, the type traits tend to test the exact type, so a reference to a type or a `const` or `volatile` version of the type will not match. There are many combinations and if you don't care about if it's a `const volatile T` or a `T&`, you can remove that from `T` before testing.
In C++20, there's a combination trait for removing both `const` and `volatile` as well as references:

```cpp
std::remove_cvref_t<T>
```

You could use it to define a `concept` that strips *all* `T`s of *cv* and *ref* s. There is already a type trait combining `is_integral_v<T> || is_floating_point_v<T>` called `is_arithmetic` so the new `concept` could look like so:

```cpp
template <class... Ts>
concept all_arithmetic =
    std::conjunction_v<std::is_arithmetic<std::remove_cvref_t<Ts>>...>;
```

`conjunction_v` is another trait that performs a logical AND over the `is_arithmetic` instances and checks each instance's `value` and stops instantiating if any `value` is `false`.

`foo` could now be defined as

```cpp
void foo(all_arithmetic auto&&...) noexcept {}

// or

template <all_arithmetic... Ts>
void foo(Ts&&...) noexcept {}

// or

template <class... Ts>
requires all_arithmetic<Ts...>
void foo(Ts&&...) noexcept {}
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you could just as well write `arithmetic auto&&` where `arithmetic` is a `concept<typename T>`, not a pack concept. This would save you the trouble of using `std::conjunction_v`. And even if you write a pack concept, what advantage is there to using `std::conjunction` instead of a trait here? Standard libraries nowadays implement all type traits as builtins, which are directly exposed in the convenience type aliases/variables like `std::is_arithmetic_v`. Using the `std::is_arithmetic` class should be strictly worse.

Comment: *I meant "instead of a fold expression here"

Comment: @JanSchultke Re _"arithmetic auto&&"_ - Good point. I don't find the use of `conjunction` troublesome though. In gcc `is_arithmetic_v = is_arithmetic<_Tp>::value` and the short-circuiting of `conjunction` avoids instantiating the rest of the `is_arithmetic<>::value`s in case a `false` is found, unlike in a fold-expression, which I like. If it's actually compiles _faster_, I don't know.